# nginx request_time is greater than actual php execution time for POST requests

Tags: php, nginx

I'm running nginx + php-fpm.

```
nginx relevant configuration:
worker_processes auto;
worker_connections 1024;
```

php-fpm relevant configuration:

```
pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 256
pm.start_servers = 32
pm.min_spare_servers = 8
pm.max_spare_servers = 32
pm.max_requests = 10000
```

from time to time (~5%) of POST requests become very slow - the request_time value in access log is about 2 seconds while it takes about 3-5 ms to php to handle the request. It's body length is about 200 bytes and response size is also pretty low - less than 1 kb.

Looks like miss configuration. Any suggestions which configuration should be tuned?

thanks.

Comment: Also, from time to time (about once in 2-3 minutes) there are requests that simply timed out after 60 seconds (they do not arrive to php). CPU usage is about 8-9%, total requests rate is 20/sec

Comment: Could it be simply slow clients? `$request_time` — time elapsed between the **first bytes were read from the client** and the log write after **the last bytes were sent to the client**

Comment: the nginx is behind the ELB, so I guess it's not the case, or am I wrong in my guess?

Comment: I don't know anything about ELB. You could log `$upstream_connect_time` and `$upstream_response_time` and compare it with PHP's time